# What does $this->input->post('submit') return when it is submitted?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I am checking my form and want to know if this would be correct. I have the same function processing two forms based on which submit button was clicked and my question is basically would the following work fine...

```
public function register()
{
    $user = $this->input->post('user_register');
    $store = $this->input->post('store_regiser');

    if($user === FALSE AND $store === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('tmp', array('tmp' => 'main/register'));
    }

    if($user != FALSE)
    {
        //User register
    }

    if($store != FALSE)
    {
        //Store register
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The logic seems a bit off - and you should really take a look at the [Form Validation Library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) for such trivial tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $value = $this->input->post('submit'); //This should match the name of your button

if( $value == "user_register" )
{

//Do what you have to do

}
else if( $value == "store_register" )
{
//Do the other logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure what $this->input->post('submit') returned exactly.

Answer (score 2):

`$this->input->post('submit')`

Will return the value of the button so using it on the below:

`<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />`

will return "Send"

Note the case sensitivity here. If it were me I would give each form a different name="" on the submit button.

so:

`<input type="submit" value="Send" name="user" />`

`<input type="submit" value="Send" name="client" />`

and then just:

`if ($this->input->post('user')) // code goes here`

`if ($this->input->post('client')) // code goes here`

The reason I would do this is that the content of the value="" property on the submit button is ment for the end user the name="" is for testing against so more appropriate for you.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just echo out the input in question?

```
echo var_dump($this->input->post());
die;
```

It should return whatever value it was given in the HTML form,

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Above would output

```
[submit] => Save
```